# why packages is not installing im my cmd

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, package

i am using anaconda 3.6.3. ,trying to install packages like Beautifulsoup,pyopenfdm etc. but it showing errors on cmd(lots of red colours errors). i even tried SET path in my command but even after that errors persisting.please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zuyru.png)

Comment: try `conda install -c anaconda beautifulsoup4` and for pip installation use **Anaconda prompt**

Comment: yes!! it worked. thank you. but how did you know that Beautifulsoup4 i should use. why this 4? any reason. why Beautifulsoup is not running but this?